# Prove $\exists x p(x) \implies ¬ \forall x q(x)$ from premise $\forall x (p(x) \implies ¬ q(x))$

Tags: logic

I am currently trying to use the Fitch system to prove the following:

Premise: $\forall x. (p(x) \implies ¬ q(x))$

and trying to arrive at

$\exists x. p(x) \implies ¬ \forall x. q(x)$

i.e., written in a different notation that may be more familiar to some,

premise:

AX:(p(X) => ~q(X))

and trying to prove

EX:p(X) => ~AX:q(X)

I am not sure if I am even correctly thinking about this, as this is an intermediate stage of a proof I am stuck on, but I am quite new to logic and I am self-studying (which is making it tough to understand some of the intricacies of these types of statements in relational logic).

If this is infeasible, I would be happy to know why this may be the case.

Comment: The goal is a conditional, so you should try a conditional proof. I don;t know the exact rules that you have to use (even when you say 'Fitch system' that's not enough, since there are different 'Fitch systems'), but in most Fitch systems a conditional proof is formalized by $\to $ Introduction ... which makes sense: you want to *obtain* (i.e. 'introduce') a conditional. That's all I am going to say for now: try that, and if you are still stuck, add your efforts  to your post, and maybe I'll provide some more hints. But you should really show a bit more effort first!

Comment: Assume $∃x p(x)$ and $∀xq(x)$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: A proof in classical logic: Assume $\exists x$ $p(x)$ is true. Thus, $p(x_0)$ is true for some $x_0$. The premise implies that $¬q(x_0)$ is true. Thus, $q(x_0)$ is false, which implies that $\forall x$ $q(x)$ is false. Thus, $¬\forall x$ $q(x)$ is true. This concludes the proof.

Now, of course, you still have to translate this to the language of the Fitch system.

Comment: @Bram28 the Fitch system I use has the following rules available: Negation Introduction/Elimination, And/Or Elimination/Introduction, Assumption, Reiteration, Implication Intro/Elim, Biconditional Intro/Elim, Existential Intro/Elim and Universal Intro/Elim. Intuitively I think there is an equivalence between the premise and the goal statements, but I am stuck trying to apply these rules to arrive at the conclusion.  Due to "x" being a free variable, I believe utilizing some witty placeholder substitution via universal elimination may be a step I need to explore.

Comment: @qxzsilver Yes, Fitch systems are characterized by having Intro and Elim rules for each of the logical operators.  But, how exactly those rules are formally defined differs from one system to the next. In fact, many of these variations involve how to deal with the quantifiers, so it that's where you're stuck, we really cannot help unless you give us the *exact* rule as defined in the system that you use.

Comment: @qxzsilver Then again: as a beginner you should probably not get too stuck on the formal particulars. It is probably far more productive to think about the inherent abstract logic behind the rules. So like I said: be able to recognize that you should do a conditional proof here (assume $\exists x \ p(x)$, and try to get to $\neg \forall x \ q(x))$ and then, inside that conditional proof, since you're trying to prove a negation ($\neg \forall x \  q(x))$, you should probably try a proof by Contradiction (most likely formalized by the $\neg$ Intro rule)

Comment: @qxzsilver By the way, the two statement are not equivalent: imagine a universe with two objects, $a$ and $b$, and where $a$ has properties $p$ and $q$ (hence the premise is false), but where $b$ lacks property $q$ (hence the goal is true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Mauro ALLEGRANZA comment I am going to use a modified version of the Fitch system I was taught.

First I am going to look at our conclusion: $\exists x(p(x)) \to \lnot \forall x(q(x))$ which is equivalent to $\exists x(p(x)) \to \exists x(\lnot q(x))$ because of DeMorgan's law and going further we know that $\lnot p \lor q \equiv p \to q$, so we will apply this to what we have in question making: $\lnot \exists x(p(x)) \lor \exists x(\lnot q(x))$ and using DeMorgan's again we get: $\forall x(\lnot p(x)) \lor \exists x(\lnot q(x))$.

What Mauro is saying is that we should assume the opposite of this so we can draw a contradiction and this will say everything we stated is false, therefore we negate what we stated and we get what we want.

$$1.\space \forall x(p(x) \to \lnot q(x)) \qquad \text{Premise.}\\
\boxed{2.\space  \exists x(p(x)) \land \forall x(q(x)) \qquad \text{Assumption} \\
3.\forall x(q(x)) \qquad \text{$\land$-elim (2)} \\
4.\space \exists x(p(x)) \qquad \text{$\land$-elim(2)} \\ 
\boxed{5.\space a \space p(a) \qquad \text{assumption} \\
6.\space p(a) \to \lnot q(a) \qquad \text{$\forall$-elim (1)} \\
7.\space \lnot q(a) \qquad \text{$\to$-elim(5,6)} \\
8.\space \exists x(\lnot q(x)) \qquad \text{$\exists$-intro(7)}} \\
9.\space \exists x(\lnot q(x)) \qquad \text{$\exists$-elim(4,5-8)} \\
10. \space \exists x(\lnot q(x)) \lor \forall x(\lnot p(x)) \space \space \text{$\lor$ -intro (9)} \\
11.F \qquad \text{$\lnot$-elim (2,10)}
} \\
12. \lnot(\exists x(p(x)) \land \forall x(q(x)))
$$

We end with what we want! If we take more of DeMorgan's laws and logical equivalences: $$\begin{align}
\lnot(\exists x(p(x)) \land \forall x(q(x))) \\
\equiv \forall x(\lnot p(x)) \lor \exists x(\lnot q(x)) \\
\equiv \lnot(\forall x(\lnot p(x))) \to \exists x(\lnot q(x)) \\
\boxed{\equiv \exists x(p(x)) \to \exists x (\lnot q(x)).}
\end{align}$$

I wanted to note some of the operations and logic I did with this system. We assume the opposite of what we want on line $2$. With the $\land$ elimination we can get both sides as true because in order for a $\land$ to be true both premises must be true. Line $5$ we assume there is a variable named $a$ that makes $p(a)$ true meaning there is only one variable which let's us apply the $\forall$ elimination. On line $8$, we introduce that there does indeed exist a variable that makes $\lnot q(a)$ true. Line $10$ we can introduce $\lor$ anything we want since we know that at least one premise is true.

Hope this helps, and maybe you can apply this to your Fitch system.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to "x" being a free variable, I believe utilizing some witty placeholder substitution via universal elimination may be a step I need to explore. - qxzsilver

Yes.  That is the correct process.

You will first need to raise a witness variable, somehow. Well, you appear to be using [Stanford Logica's proof checker](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) which implements Existential Elimination by: checking a line with an existential statement, clicking 'Existential Elimination', to instantiate the predicate with a new witness variable: eg  `q([c1])` or such.

Once that is done, then you may use 'Universal Elimination' to instantiate a universal statement's predicate to the same term.

---

The skeleton of the proof is to take `AX:(p(X) => ~q(X))` as a premise, and use a conditional proof to derive `EX:q(X) => ~AX:q(X)`.

That requires raising `EX:q(X)` as an assumption, then derive `~AX:q(X)` so you may then use Introduction Introduction.   Existential Elimination will be involved inside this sub-proof.

You thus need to derive `~AX:q(X)` using negation introduction; the implementation of which in [Stanford Logica](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) requires two implications each with `AX:q(X)` as their antecedents, and having contradictory consequents. For this, `AX:q(X) => p([c1])` and `AX:q(X) => ~p([c1])` will do nicely, because these can readily be derived.

Well, that will get you started, so I'll leave the rest to you.

```
1. AX:(p(X) => ~q(X))            Premise
    2. EX:p(X)                   Assumption
    3. p([c1])                   Existential Elimination: 2
    :
    10. AX:q(X) => ~p([c1])      Implication Introduction: 4, 9
    :
    13. AX:q(X) => p([c1])       Implication Introduction: 11, 12
    14. ~AX:q(X)                 Negation Introduction: 13, 10
15. EX:p(X) => ~AX:q(X)          Implication Introduction: 2, 14
```

Comment: I believe existential elimination is not possible in my current assumptions - Existential Elimination is defined as:

Comment: $\exists v.\phi$

Comment: $\forall v.(\phi \implies \psi$)

Comment: ---------------------------------

Comment: $\psi$, where $v$ does not occur free in $\psi$

Comment: Of course the exact implementation depends on the rules of inference you are using, but if the system is complete then it will be derivable.